# How to check whether there is some specific keys or not in object in js

Tags: javascript

I want to get this result by some logic through a validate for 'key'.

```
const validateOfKey= [ 'a', 'b' ] 

const pass1 = { a: 3, b: 4 } // true
const pass2 = { a: 3 } // true

const pass3 = { a:3, c:5, .. } // false
const pass4 = { a:3, b:4, c:3...} // false
const pass5 = { d:3, e:5 ...} // false
```

I can use hasOwnProperty for some case. But in my case, this is a little bit hard for me to make this logic.
Can you recommend some advice for resolving this ? Thank you so much for reading it.

Comment: Why is pass4 false?

Comment: @kooskoos sorry, it was mis typed..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Object.keys()` to get an array of keys, and check if every key is included in the list of valid keys:

```js
const fn = (validKeys, obj) =>
  Object.keys(obj)
    .every(k => validKeys.includes(k))

const validateOfKey= ['a', 'b'] 

console.log(fn(validateOfKey, { a: 3, b: 4 })) // true
console.log(fn(validateOfKey, { a: 3 })) // true

console.log(fn(validateOfKey, { a:3, c:5 })) // false
console.log(fn(validateOfKey, { d:3, e:5 })) // false
```

Answer (score 2):

You could take a `Set` and check against the keys from the object.

```js
function has(object, keys) {
    return Object.keys(object).every(Set.prototype.has, new Set(keys));
}

const keys = ['a', 'b'];

console.log(has({ a: 3, b: 4 }, keys));       //  true - all keys
console.log(has({ a: 3 }, keys));             //  true - subset of keys
console.log(has({ a: 3, c: 5 }, keys));       // false - some other key/s
console.log(has({ a: 3, b: 4, x: 3 }, keys)); // false - some other key/s
console.log(has({ d: 3, e: 5 }, keys));       // false - no wanted keys
```

Comment: Nice use of set and every!
Minor gripes; I feel the name 'has' is misleading as the object _may_ have the keys, but may not have any other keys. Also, changing the argument order would be useful for currying (data last).

Answer (score 1):

iterate through all keys in validateOfKey array and check if the given object contains that key. for this we use "key in Object"

```
var validate = inputObj => {
    let validateOfKey = ["a", "b"];

    for (let i = 0; i < validateOfKey.length; i++) {
      if (!(validateOfKey[i] in inputObj)) {
        return false;
      }
      return true;
    }
  };
```

pass any object to above function to check against keys in validateOfKey.
also you can modify validateOfKey as per your needs.